# Getting around pairing pin exchange on an android system without GUI and HAL

Tags: android, bluetooth, pairing, hci

On an Android System *without* a bluetooth-hal and only
`hciconfig, hcitool, sdptool and rfcomm` I want to pair host and device (host: Asus BT400 dongle).
On the Android system I do

```
hciconfig hci0 up
hciconfig hci0 sspmode 1
sdptool add SP
rfcomm ...
```

on the host I start `bluetoothctl`
and do

```
power on
agent on
default-agent
scan on
pair <bd-addr>
```

however now I am asked for the PIN.

The target Andoid has *no bluetooth-hal and no GUI*, there is no pin diablog. Still I would like to retrieve the pin
for this system so that I can pair from the host.

Can I retrieve the PIN via commandline?

Can I recompile the Android kernel and printk() the pin if somebody knows
the place where it appears?

I cannot use any other bluez tools other than the available `hciconfig, hcitool, sdptool and rfcomm` but if there is some ioctl() or socket to connect to
to watch for the pin appearing I could maybe write my own c-snippet? Where is the place to look for a template for such a util?

What is the easiest way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also compiled `btmgmt` on target. With `btmgmt` running both on target and host I can start a pairing cycle from console and enter PIN in console.
Looking into the sourceode of `btmgmt` it seems possible to automate the pairing by watching for MGMT_OP_PIN_CODE_REPLY event and sending MGMT_EV_PIN_CODE_REQUEST to automate it.